# How to create a transparent bitmap / drawable in android using drawing lines and circles on a canvas

Tags: android

It seems to be a very trivial thing, but I am not able to find a sample code for it.

I am trying to do a very simple thing. On a canvas I plan to draw a round rect and save that in a drawable which I can then set as a background of a button.

Now I am looking for 2 things, how to draw and create a round rect so that the transparency effect can be created (like in a png drawable)
Second how to save the canvas to an image.

Please help

Comment: did you want to assign canvas as background of button?

Comment: you dont have to save it, if you want to use it as a Drawable just create a class that extends Drawable

Comment: I lplan to create a round rect drawable which serves as a background of a button with transparent rounds

Comment: what does it mean: transparent rounds?

Comment: something like this image http://i292.photobucket.com/albums/mm30/enchantedmys/tutorials/tutid.png

Comment: cant use that, the size of the button is variable and decided on run time

Comment: again, use nine patch drawable, it is designed for such purposes

Comment: pardon my ignorance on that. Ca you please suggest a sample code

Comment: ask google for  nine patch drawable

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code.

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.color.transparant);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```